# How to increase the saved sessions list font in Putty?

Tags: putty

I've increased font in the terminal already but the problem with tiny font of saved session list remains.Is it possible to increase this font?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The (text) size in the PuTTY configuration and settings window is, AFAIK not adjustable from within PuTTY.

The only way to increase that, is by using the generic Windows Display settings option: "Make everything bigger" which changes the size of all apps and text on your display.

That will, as the name implies, not only adjust the PuTTY Window and text sizes, but all apps.

The option is per display, so I mainly use it on my large 5K external display but the effect on my normal laptop display looks like:

## Normal at 100%

[image: 100% scaling]

## Scale up to 175%

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on saved session name, click Load, then go to menu to set font, set the size you want, return to sessions and click Save.

If you talk about the font which used to display the names of saved sessions I am afraid you can't directly from putty change it.

Comment: This will change font for the session. I need to change the font for the session list (for example increase the font of "Centos7" entry).

Comment: @XorOrNor, updated with info about the text you mention.